# Prepend to block of text, but ignore blank lines

Tags: text-editing, rectangle

How to add the string 'export ' to the beginning of each line of this text,
with emacs:

```
RBENV_VERSION="2.n.0"

AUTHORIZE_NET_API_LOGIN_ID=example
AUTHORIZE_NET_TRANSACTION_KEY=example

# Google Calendar Integration

# Google Calendar
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=example
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=example

# Live Mailchimp keys
MAILCHIMP_API_KEY=example
```

Comment: `C-x ( string C-a C-n C-x )`, then `C-u 99 C-x e`

Comment: @Drew I agree this answers the question in the text, but not the question in the title. I further suspect that the OP would like to skip lines starting with `#`. A non macro way to do the same would be to use C-x C-r t, string-rectangle once the start and end positions were marked.

Comment: in my experience, C-x C-r t adds to the blank lines too

Comment: Yes, C-x C-r t will have the same, undesired effect of adding to blank and comment lines that the keyboard macro does.

Answer (score 1):

An answer to a different question would be to add

```
 _oldflags=$- ; set -a
```

as the first line of the file and

```
 [[ "$_oldflags" =~ a ]] || set +a ; unset _oldflags
```

which tells bash to export all the variables (the set -a) and restore the state of the "set -a" flag at the end. If you never use "set -a" then this can be simplified to adding "set -a" at the start and "set +a" at the end.

Comment: wow didn't see that coming

Comment: @american-ninja-warrior It is helpful to ask oneself what a questioner wants to achieve rather than what is actually being asked. see for example https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
(defun doit ()
  (interactive)
  (while (not (eobp))
    (beginning-of-line)
    (when (looking-at "[A-Z]")
      (insert "export "))
    (next-line)))
```

This will walk through the lines starting at the cursor until the end of the buffer, and if the line starts with a capital letter (per the given regular expression range), then it will prepend with the string.

To use, paste this into *scratch*, position your cursor after the last close paren, and hit C-x C-e to load the definition. Then go to the buffer with your text, position your cursor on the first line you want to change, and invoke with `M-x doit`.

Of course this could be enhanced to only work in a region, parameterize in various ways, etc.

Another option, if you don't want to define a function, is to adapt the approach into a macro like this:

1. Go to the first line you want to change in your buffer
2. Type C-x ( to start recording macro
3. Type C-a to go to beginning of line (don't skip this step even if you're already at the beginning of the line)
4. Type M-: to bring up the "Eval:" prompt and enter `(when (looking-at "[A-Z]") (insert "export "))`
5. Type C-n to go to the next line
6. End the macro with C-x )
7. Repeat the macro a bunch of times: C-u 10 C-x e